# Create database by manifest when deploying with Jelastic Packaging Standard

Tags: jelastic

I'm trying to write a manifest for JPS deployment of an Jelastic application.
Creating nodes and deploying webapps works fine but I can't create a database and load a sql dump into it using the manifest directives.

My configs section looks like this:

"configs": [
             {
                "nodeType": "postgres9",
                "restart": false, 
                "database": [{
                               "name": "somedbname",
                               "user" : "someusername",
                                "dump": "http://www.somehost.de/jelastic/somedump.sql"
                             }]
                 },
             ... 
             ]
 ...

It seems that the database section is completely ignored.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have an extra square brackets around database object definition, i.e. you must have **"database" : { ... }**, instead of **"database" : [{...}]**

Also I can suggest you to review an example from [Cyclos](http://www.cyclos.org/jelastic/cyclos4.json). Their idea is to download an executable bash script which will be started by cron and do all the things required for setting the database up, including adding of a new user, extensions etc.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, we corrected this. We now have a working manifest with a "database" section for a tomcat7/mysql5 deployment but it still fails for tomcat7/postgres9 deployments. It seems that there's a bug in Jelastic because it reports a deployment error saying that it can't establish a mysql connection (though it should connect to postgres9). Maybe the Cyclos guys had the same problem so they avoided the "database" json configuration and used cron and a shell script instead.

Comment: Yes, we sent a bug report.